# Behavior of $PreRead in Kernel

Tags: kernel, customization, command-line

I am interested in making a simple accounting style line calculator that allows me to interact with it something like this:

```
In[]:   4 + 5
Out[]:  9
In[]:   +3
Out[]:  12
In[]:   *2
Out[]:  24
In[]:   /4
Out[]:  6
```

In the front end, I can do this with:

```
$PreRead = (ReplaceAll[#, {"*" :> "% *", "+" :> "% +", "-" :> "% - ", 
 "/" :> "% /"}] &)
```

(And stop it by `$PreRead =.`) which works nicely, however I would like to use the numberpad, and the <kbd>+</kbd> key on the number pad starts a free form input.

So, I thought I'd be sneaky and open up a kernel window.  Sadly, the above assignment of `$PreRead` doesn't seem to execute in the `Kernel`, even though it looks like the variable has been assigned properly.

I'm interested in why `$PreRead` isn't behaving the same in the `Kernel` window as it would in the `FrontEnd`, and it wouldn't hurt to know if it is possible to shut off the keymapping of the numberpad + key to free form input.

Comment: `$PreRead` does not seem to work in a kernel window on mac, on versions 9.0.1 and 10.3. I guess it never worked in versions in between.

Answer (score 2):

To make `$PreRead` work when using the command line / text based interface, you may have to start the kernel with the `-rawterm` option. This works for me on OSX, MMA version `11.0.1`. When I say "use `-rawterm`" I mean start the kernel like this (from a terminal window): `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -rawterm`. If you have started the kernel in this way, `$PreRead = Echo` will print stuff, whereas this does nothing without the `-rawterm` option.

The following definition then seems to do what you want

```
$PreRead = 
  StringReplace[#, 
    op : "*" | "+" | "-" | "/" ~~ sq___ :> "%" ~~ op ~~ sq] &;
```

Note that using `-rawterm` also means you do not have access to a lot of the improvements that were made to the text based interface, like being able to move the cursor around with the arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, for having a look at my problem here.  Your function `myPre` doesn't seem to work as intended on the RPi version.  If I do something like `$Pre = ToString[#]&` I would hope to capture the user input as a string; however it looks like `*2` is parsed (and throws an error) prior to being converted to a string.

Comment: @bobthechemist yes, you are right. I just tested if `$PreRead` works on a RPi, but apparently it doesn't. What you see in the answer is really an afterthought, when what I expected didn't work. Maybe I'll try to make something work using pipes.

Answer (score 1):

*This doesn't seem to work on Mac*

---

You can check with  `$PreRead = Echo` (or `Print` in case of V<10.3) that `+1` returns `RowBox[{+,1}]` in `FrontEnd` and `"+1"` in `Kernel`.

So the solution is to use:

```
$PreRead = StringReplace[#, StartOfString ~~ op : "*" | "+" | "-" | "/" :> "%" <> op] &
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, for me setting a value to `$PreRead` does nothing in the kernel.

Comment: I would switch to windows, but the `Timing` is bad ;)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I suppose that withput `$PreRead` you need to combine `$Pre` and `$SyntaxHandler`. Does `$SyntaxHandler` work for you e.g. when you type *1?

Comment: ah yes, I had already checked `$SyntaxHandler`. That one does work. So you mean to cause a syntax error using `$Pre`? Ingenious, but quite hacky too :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom not really, :) with `$Pre` is too late for `$SyntaxHandler`. But I mean you have to use it for "*2" and "/2" since this is incorrect syntax so you can/have to catch them and insert %. And about + and -, `$Pre` should work at the end, shouldn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32052/discussion-between-jacob-akkerboom-and-kuba).

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this problem - I can't seem to reproduce your results using the RPi version (10.0)